# Websocket Manager with Playframework and Scala

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework, broadcast

I want to use web sockets because I need to notify my users when there is a new message for them. And I’ve done a lot of research and I’m pretty sure I need to use WebSockets for this problem.

I was able to connect to my backend with the following steps: https://www. playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWebSockets

This allows my frontend to connect to my backend and has received the answer from the backend.

But how is it possible to manage all currently active web socket connections? Is there a method that I can use to find all active connections? Or do I have to implement all this from scratch?

Comment: Newest sbt is 1.6.1, are you sure it's not 1.4.0?

Comment: I'd expect that you need to implement it yourself, especially, since a single app that is not a part of a cluster (it doesn't have to be) would not be aware of other instances'/nodes' connections.